# Javascript: Object.keys(myarray).forEach vs myarray.forEach((obj) => {

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

Is there an alternative way of looping through my array of objects? it seems the engine version on the application im using is old and doesnt support `myArray.forEach((obj) => {` but this works on an single object array I think. `Object.keys(myArray).forEach(`

> {"jurisdiction":"SCPB - LON"},{"firstName":"David Dynamic"}

```
var array = []

$('input:checked').each(function() {

        var key_ = $(this).attr('name')
        var val = $(this).attr('name').val();

        var obj = {
            [key_]: val
        };
        array.push(obj);

        array.forEach((obj) => {
                    Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => {
                            alert(key: " + key + " - value: " + obj[key]);
                            });
                    });
});
```

**Error produced by the webapp**

> ```
> JST-310000 Error while compiling script '_webApp_APP303__preview' line 175: syntax error (line='     array.forEach((obj) => {
> ' token='> {
> ').
> SCR-160032 JavaScript: error while compiling script '_webApp_APP303__preview'.
> ```

Also tried a loop to no avail.

```
array.forEach(obj => {
  
  for (let key in obj) {
    logInfo(`${key}: ${obj[key]}`);
  }

});
```

> JST-310000 Error while compiling script '_webApp_APP303__preview' line
> 176: syntax error (line='array.forEach(obj => { ' token='> { ').
> SCR-160032 JavaScript: error while compiling script
> '_webApp_APP303__preview'.

Comment: Your indentation is poor and you have missing brackets. Please post valid code with readable indentation. Also, where is the declaration of `mergeData`?

Comment: What JavaScript version are you using? `array.forEach()` is not very new.

Comment: What about... a `for` loop?

Comment: @Barmar i think spidermonkey

Comment: SpiderMonkey is the Firefox engine, and it has fully supported Array.forEach forever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message you have added shows that this particular JavaScript engine does not support arrow function syntax, as it trips over the `=>` token, already at the *outer* loop.

The solution is to use `function` callbacks only:

```
    array.forEach(function (obj) {
        Object.keys(obj).forEach(function (key) {
            alert("key: " + key + " - value: " + obj[key]);
        });
    });
```